# How can a LOAD segment have an offset of 0?

Tags: operating-system, elf, readelf

Look at this readelf of an ELF file, the first LOAD segment has offset 0.

How is that even possible? Isn't the ELF header at offset 0?

readelf -l

[image: 1]

Comment: "How is that even possible?" -- why not? It's hard to answer your question, because you didn't explain _why_ you believe offset `0` is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ELF header is at offset 0, which means that it will be loaded into the virtual memory of the process that runs the executable. Note that it's marked read-only, and not executable. The second `LOAD` segment has an `E` in the flags column, so that's probably the `.text` section.